# Xamarin Audio Player Progress bar inconsistency

Tags: visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I am having an issue with progress bar in Xamarin Android. I am using the below code for playing a specific audio file.

```
await CrossMediaManager.Current.Play(await DependencyService.Get<IMedia>().GetPath(answer.ResourceURL));
```

and the progress bar code is like this :

```
CrossMediaManager.Current.PlayingChanged += (sender, ev) =>
                            {
                                progressBar.Progress = ev.Position.TotalSeconds / ev.Duration.TotalSeconds;
                                elapseTime.Text = Math.Abs(ev.Position.TotalMinutes).ToString("0.00");
                                totalTime.Text = Math.Abs((ev.Duration.TotalMinutes) - ev.Position.TotalMinutes).ToString("0.00");
                            };
```

I have placed this progress bar code after the play.
So now my issue is like, in my screen there are some audio files for example 5 with 5 play buttons.
If I click on 2nd file, the audio is playing perfect. But the progress bar for the 5th file is also being moved but the audio is not played. Only the progress bar is moved.
Please find the attached image.[Screenshot for progress bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8WinZ.png)

if I place the progress bar code in my constructor, all the progress bars of all the files are being moved but only one file is being played.

Some one please help me out fix this issue.

Comment: Can you please show your layout for 5 play buttons and 5 progressbar?

Comment: `<Image x:Name="xplay" Source="play_circle.png" >                                    <Image.GestureRecognizers>                                        <TapGestureRecognizer  Tapped="TrackEntity3" NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
</Image.GestureRecognizers>
 </Image>
<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
 <Label  x:Name="elapseTime" HorizontalOptions="Start" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"></Label>
  <Label  x:Name="totalTime" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" HorizontalTextAlignment="End"></Label>                                </StackLayout>
<ProgressBar   x:Name="progressBar" />`

Comment: I am using card component, which will be iterated based on the number of files from the DB in my ViewModel. the count of the files is dynamic. @Grace Feng

Answer (score 0):

> I am using card component, which will be iterated based on the number of files from the DB in my ViewModel. the count of the files is dynamic.

I'm not sure which control are you using, but based on your description, it's possible that you're using `ListView` or `RecyclerView` or something like it, whose items can be automatically inserted to the list using an `Adapter`.

Then, for the controls like this, it is not recommended to use its name for retrieving the instance of the control in the item, cause each item has a control with the same name, especially that you're using Xamarin.Forms for development, if you're using the [ListView](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/) in PCL and `DataTemplate` for the `ItemTemplate`, it's like a structure for each item.

Assume that you're using the `ListView` in PCL, not in Android platform, then you can for example code like this.

Firstly create a subclass of `Image` so we can give an ID to each item, for example:

```
public class MyImage : Image
{
    public int ItemID
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(ItemIDProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemIDProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty ItemIDProperty = BindableProperty.Create<MyImage, int>(p => p.ItemID, default(int));
}
```

Then use is in XAML for example:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:YOURNAMESPACE"
             x:Class="YOURNAMESPACE.MainPage">
    <ContentPage.Content>

            <ListView x:Name="lv">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="Fill">
                                <local:MyImage x:Name="xplay" Source="play_circle.png" ItemID="{Binding id}">
                                    <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TrackEntity3" NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
                                    </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                </local:MyImage>
                                <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Orientation="Vertical">
                                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <Label x:Name="elapseTime" HorizontalOptions="Start" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" Text="{Binding elapsetime,Mode=OneWay}"></Label>
                                        <Label x:Name="totalTime" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" HorizontalTextAlignment="End" Text="{Binding totaltime,Mode=OneWay}"></Label>
                                    </StackLayout>
                                    <ProgressBar x:Name="progressBar" WidthRequest="300"  Progress="{Binding progress,Mode=OneWay}" />
                                </StackLayout>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>

    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Create a data model:

```
public class MyMedia : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public int id { get; set; }

    private string _elapsetime;

    public string elapsetime
    {
        get { return _elapsetime; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _elapsetime)
            {
                _elapsetime = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    private string _totaltime;

    public string totaltime
    {
        get { return _totaltime; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _totaltime)
            {
                _totaltime = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    private double _progress;

    public double progress
    {
        get { return _progress; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _progress)
            {
                _progress = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

In the `TrackEntity3` event:

```
private MyMedia currentItem;

private void TrackEntity3(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var image = sender as MyImage;
    var id = image.ItemID;
    foreach (var source in lv.ItemsSource)
    {
        var item = source as MyMedia;
        if (item.id == id)
        {
            //play music here
            //find labels and progressbar
            if (currentItem != null)
            {
                currentItem.progress = 0;
                currentItem.totaltime = "";
                currentItem.elapsetime = "";
            }
            currentItem = item;
        }
    }
}
```

In the `CrossMediaManager.Current.PlayingChanged` event directly change the item like this:

```
CrossMediaManager.Current.PlayingChanged += (sender, ev) =>
                            {
                                currentItem.progress = ...;
                                currentItem.elapsetime = ...;
                                currentItem.totaltime = ...;

                            };
```

Since it's a `ListView`, you can add items use `ObservableCollection`:

```
private ObservableCollection<MyMedia> collection = new ObservableCollection<MyMedia>();

public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        collection.Add(new MyMedia { id = i });
    }
    lv.ItemsSource = collection;
}
```

And sounds like you're using MVVM pattern, you can move the code in behind to your viewmodel. And if you're using other control for dynamically adding items, you can leave a comment.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response.

Comment: In one way, I am iterating through ListView only.

Please find the code below:

`<ContentPage>
 <StackLayout>
  <ListView.ItemTemplate >
     <DataTemplate>
      <ViewCell>
            <card:PlayersComponent/>
          </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
      </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
  </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>`






The below is my design comp0nent

`<ContentView  x:Class="AudioPlayer.PCL.Components.PlayerCards.PlayersComponent">
 <StackLayout>  

  //Design of Play Buttons and progress bar are here 

 </StackLayout>
</ContentView>`

Comment: @Navya, yeah, you used your `card:PlayersComponent`, it's OK, I just provided a sample code, since your tapped event is attached to the image, so, it's important to use the image itself to find the relative item, and use data binding and `INotifyPropertyChanged` to notify if the data source is changed.